# Problems with expansions in search results with Twitter v2 API

Tags: twitter

I am able to successfully retrieve tweets with historical searches using the Twitter v2 API.  However, when I try to use the 'expansions' parameter, it returns the expansion field (e.g. author_id) but never includes the expansion object (in the case the 'user') in the JSON.  Here's what my Postman GET query string looks like:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all?expansions=author_id&query=covid-19%20testing%20site%20-is:retweet&user.fields=name '''
```

And the json that gets returned is properly formatted and begins like this:

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "author_id": "31220292",
        "id": "1417588897450766340",
        "text": "As travel begins to reopen amid COVID-19, the Manitoba government is opening a testing site for the virus at the province’s largest airport."
    },
    {
        "author_id": "21212604",
        "id": "1417585941229735936",
        "text": "NEW: Some COVID-19 vaccination clinics and at least one testing site will be closing this week as demand for vaccines slows down and COVID-19 case counts remain low. #ottnews"
    },
```

I've done a lot of experimenting with different types of expansions (e.g. geo.place_id), but none of them seem to work.

Also, I've tried using the sample queries from Twitters API documentation:

curl 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/:ID?expansions=geo.place_id’ --header 'Authorization: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN'

And those queries don't work at all.  The seem to choke on the '/:ID?' part of the url.